# Help with an integral involving the logarithm of $(q;q)_{\infty}$

Tags: special-functions, indefinite-integrals, modular-forms

We have the integral :
$$\int_{1}^{q}(z-1)\frac{d}{dz}\log\phi\left(z^{-s} \right )dz$$
Where :
$$\phi(q)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{k})$$
And $s$ is a complex variable in the right half plane. I tried using :
$$\log\phi(z^{-s})=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{z^{ks}-1}$$
But that didn't help much. I also tried :
$$\log\phi(z^{-s})=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma(k)}{k}z^{-ks}$$
$\sigma(k)$ being the divisor function, but that didn't help either. Any insights are appreciated.